# Zip and Encrypt Files in memory Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, zip

I was trying to zip a few files and password protect them.
The catch here is I cannot save the file on the disk.

I tried using Rubyzip. But seems like it doesn't support file encryption.

I tried using Zipruby but it only allows Encrypting the files already on the disk. (I am not sure about this, but I could not find a way to do it in memory).

I want to Zip and Encrypt Files in memory in Ruby.

Comment: ok. so what is the question?

Comment: I want to Zip and Encrypt Files in memory in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Zipruby includes facilities to do this:

```
zipinmem = Zip::Archive.open_buffer(buf, Zip::CREATE) do |ar| #create zip
  ar.add_buffer('bar.txt', 'baz')
end
Zip::Archive.open_buffer(zipinmem) do |ar|
  ar.add_buffer('thing.txt', "We're modifying the archive in memory!")
end
```

See the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home) in the fifth section.

Comment: But how do I encrypt this buffer without saving ? As the files are encrypted in 4th Section in the same documentation.

Comment: @Harshac: in one of the zipruby blocks, call `ar.encrypt('password')`.

Comment: It didn't encrypt, but didn't even raise NoMethodError !

Comment: Yes. I'm on ruby 1.8.7 & rails 3.0

Comment: From the documentation it seems like this is possible; however, in reality it does not work.  When working with archive objects from "open_buffer" the "encrypt" method returns true but, in fact, does not encrypt the ZIP archive.

Comment: @maerics: Od. What version?

Comment: @Linuxios: I've verified on current (0.3.6); looks like a [known issue for at least one year](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/issue/3/encryption-is-a-no-op).

Comment: @maerics: Wow. Not much any of us can do about it then, is there (unless you or me can fix it).